# Crash on Samsung with Android 9: Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "csju" on path: DexPathList

Tags: marketing-cloud, error

At crashlytics, on April 7 and April 11 we had a crash peak with users using Samsung with Android 9, related to the Salesforce 8.0.8 library and google services.
Message:

```
com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.<init> (:com.google.android.gms@231213026@23.12.13 (100306-520023152):4)
java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzg (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:5)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:28)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zze.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzj.selectModule (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:5)
com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:5)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.http.c.a (Fuente desconocida:2)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.http.c.a
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a (Fuente desconocida:692)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.a (Fuente desconocida:47)
com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk$a.run (Fuente desconocida:38)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
un(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Is this a little temporary bug or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Open a support case.